# Spring Batch JDBCPagingItemReader is not invoked from slaveStep

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-batch, batch-processing

I created a POC project in which I am moving Employee table 10 records to NewEmployee table using Spring batch local partitioning steps. I have configured 4 threads to run this batch process.
when I ran this batch process, I could see that pagingItemReader() method is not invoked by slave step.Due to this OraclePagingQueryProvider is not invoked. 
I noticed the number records missed(not moved)is equal to number of threads configured.
I have developed this POC taking guidance from following link:-    https://github.com/mminella/LearningSpringBatch/tree/master/src/localPartitioning

Please note that below code works fine when I replace master and slave code with normal reading , processing and writing logic where no multi-threading is involved.

The BATCH_STEP_EXECUTION table in DB also says only 8 record moved.(here 2 records again missed which is equal to number of threads). DB Record says as follows :-

STEP_NAME   STATUS  COMMIT_COUNT    READ_COUNT  WRITE_COUNT EXIT_CODE
slaveStep:partition1    COMPLETED   1   4   4   COMPLETED
slaveStep:partition0    COMPLETED   1   4   4   COMPLETED
masterStep  COMPLETED   2   8   8   COMPLETED

The code snippet of Configuration class

```
         @Bean
                public JobRegistryBeanPostProcessor jobRegistrar() throws Exception{
                    JobRegistryBeanPostProcessor registrar=new JobRegistryBeanPostProcessor();
                    registrar.setJobRegistry(this.jobRegistry);
                    registrar.setBeanFactory(this.applicationContext.getAutowireCapableBeanFactory());
                    registrar.afterPropertiesSet();
                    return registrar;
                }

                @Bean
                public JobOperator jobOperator() throws Exception{
                    SimpleJobOperator simpleJobOperator=new SimpleJobOperator();
                    simpleJobOperator.setJobLauncher(this.jobLauncher);
                    simpleJobOperator.setJobParametersConverter(new DefaultJobParametersConverter());
                    simpleJobOperator.setJobRepository(this.jobRepository);
                    simpleJobOperator.setJobExplorer(this.jobExplorer);
                    simpleJobOperator.setJobRegistry(this.jobRegistry);

                    simpleJobOperator.afterPropertiesSet();
                    return simpleJobOperator;

                }

                @Bean
                public ColumnRangePartitioner partitioner() {
                    ColumnRangePartitioner partitioner = new ColumnRangePartitioner();
                    partitioner.setColumn("id");
                    partitioner.setDataSource(this.dataSource);
                    partitioner.setTable("Employee");
                    LOGGER.info("partitioner---->"+partitioner);
                    return partitioner;
                }

                @Bean
                public Step masterStep() {
                    return stepBuilderFactory.get("masterStep")
                            .partitioner(slaveStep().getName(), partitioner())
                            .step(slaveStep())
                            .gridSize(gridSize)
                            .taskExecutor(taskExecutorConfiguration.taskExecutor())
                            .build();
                }

                @Bean
                public Step slaveStep() {
                    return stepBuilderFactory.get("slaveStep")
                            .<Employee, NewEmployee>chunk(chunkSize)
                            .reader(pagingItemReader(null,null))
                            .processor(employeeProcessor())
                            .writer(employeeWriter.customItemWriter())
                            .build();
                }

                @Bean
                public Job job() {
                    return jobBuilderFactory.get("FR")
                            .start(masterStep())
                            .build();
                }

                @Bean
                public ItemProcessor<Employee, NewEmployee> employeeProcessor() {
                    return new EmployeeProcessor();
                }

                @Override
                public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext) throws BeansException {
                    this.applicationContext=applicationContext;
                }


                 */

                @Bean
                @StepScope
                public JdbcPagingItemReader<Employee> pagingItemReader(@Value("#{stepExecutionContext['minValue']}") Long minvalue,
                        @Value("#{stepExecutionContext['maxValue']}") Long maxvalue) {

                    JdbcPagingItemReader<Employee> reader = new JdbcPagingItemReader<Employee>();
                    reader.setDataSource(this.dataSource);
                    // this should be equal to chunk size for the performance reasons.
                    reader.setFetchSize(chunkSize);
                    reader.setRowMapper((resultSet, i) -> {
                        return new Employee(resultSet.getLong("id"), 
                                resultSet.getString("firstName"),
                                resultSet.getString("lastName"));
                    });

                    OraclePagingQueryProvider provider = new OraclePagingQueryProvider();
                    provider.setSelectClause("id, firstName, lastName");
                    provider.setFromClause("from Employee");
                    LOGGER.info("min-->"+minvalue);
                    LOGGER.info("max-->"+maxvalue);
                    provider.setWhereClause("where id<=" + minvalue + " and id > " + maxvalue);

                    Map<String, Order> sortKeys = new HashMap<>(1);
                    sortKeys.put("id", Order.ASCENDING);
                    provider.setSortKeys(sortKeys);

                    reader.setQueryProvider(provider);
                    LOGGER.info("reader--->"+reader);
                    return reader;
                }

      @Override
        public Map<String, ExecutionContext> partition(int gridSize) {
            int min = jdbcTemplate.queryForObject("SELECT MIN(" + column + ") from " + table, Integer.class);
            int max = jdbcTemplate.queryForObject("SELECT MAX(" + column + ") from " + table, Integer.class);
            int targetSize = (max - min) / gridSize + 1;

            Map<String, ExecutionContext> result = new HashMap<String, ExecutionContext>();
            int number = 0;
            int start = min;
            int end = start + targetSize - 1;

            while (start <= max) {
                ExecutionContext value = new ExecutionContext();
                result.put("partition" + number, value);

                if (end >= max) {
                    end = max;
                }
                LOGGER.info("Start-->" + start);
                LOGGER.info("end-->" + end);
                value.putInt("minValue", start);
                value.putInt("maxValue", end);
                start += targetSize;
                end += targetSize;
                number++;
            }

            return result;
        }
```

The code snippet of ColumnRangePartitioner class:-

```
 int min = jdbcTemplate.queryForObject("SELECT MIN(" + column + ") from " + table, Integer.class);
    int max = jdbcTemplate.queryForObject("SELECT MAX(" + column + ") from " + table, Integer.class);
    int targetSize = (max - min) / gridSize + 1;

    Map<String, ExecutionContext> result = new HashMap<String, ExecutionContext>();
    int number = 0;
    int start = min;
    int end = start + targetSize - 1;

    while (start <= max) {
        ExecutionContext value = new ExecutionContext();
        result.put("partition" + number, value);

        if (end >= max) {
            end = max;
        }
        LOGGER.info("Start-->" + start);
        LOGGER.info("end-->" + end);
        value.putInt("minValue", start);
        value.putInt("maxValue", end);
        start += targetSize;
        end += targetSize;
        number++;
    }

    return result;
```

Comment: Have you verified that the `Partitioner` is returning partitions?  Are the worker step execution records in the job repository?

Comment: Hi Michael- Thanks for replying. I have updated the question with BATCH_STEP_EXECUTION table records. Here I could see only 8 records is read by reader out of 10(number of records missed is equal to number of threads).Also while reading reader is not reading second column data from source table, it is copying the value of first column to second column and same is getting saved in destination table. Please note that none of these issues exists when I have removed partition logic. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution of this problem. We have to add partitionHandler in the masterStep after partitioner. In the partitionHandler we define the slaveStep and other configuration. Following is the code snippet.

MasterStep:- Add partitionHandler code here ,

```
     stepBuilderFactory
            .get("userMasterStep")
            .partitioner(userSlaveStep().getName(), userPartitioner())
            .partitionHandler(userMasterSlaveHandler())
            .build();
```

Define another bean named partitionHandler and call the slave step here

```
   @Bean
public PartitionHandler userMasterSlaveHandler() throws Exception {
    TaskExecutorPartitionHandler handler = new TaskExecutorPartitionHandler();
    handler.setGridSize(gridSize);
    handler.setTaskExecutor(taskExecutorConfiguration.taskExecutor());
    handler.setStep(userSlaveStep());
    handler.afterPropertiesSet();
    return handler;
}
```